# How do i get Last TextView's Data from Row of customlistview?

Tags: android, custom-lists

I want to get Last textview from row that was being clicked by user

for ex,

I have clicked on first row then i will get "Single Cheese Topping"

So How Do i implement the onclicklistener any suggestion please.

[image]

Comment: What kinds of adapter are you using? And can you post your code related to listview?

Comment: Do you have any code already? Show at least your OnClickListener callback methods and the XML for your row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For listview, you should use **OnItemClickListener** instead of **OnClickListener**. Here's you go.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View viewGroup, int position,
            long arg3) {
        TextView lastTextView = (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.last_textview_id);
        String lastText = lastTextView.getText().toString();

    }

});
```

Second parameter return your row layout ViewGroup. You just use findViewById to get the view you need to use from the row layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener (){

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                        long arg3)
```

here arg0 has the name of the item at index presses. you can get the name like this

```
name=arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

and you are done

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply but it is not working, Because you are trying to get data by position which will not gonna help me in my custom listview.